# PHP file insted of showing output on screen create a csv file if it does not exist then add data to it

Tags: php, forms, csv, http-post

Okay i have the following php file that output YouTube video title description and thumb URL on screen using echo statements.

Is there any way i can every time a user submits a video id instead of outputting the text on screen just echo the message done

then i want it to check if id.csv exists if it does not then create id.csv else carry on

then i want it to and the title description and thumb URL in separate cells side by side

i do not have much knowledge on php and csv together so any help an examples would really help

find my php script below

Video ID:

```
<?php
//The Youtube's API url
define('YT_API_URL', 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=');

//Change below the video id.
$video_id = $_POST['Vid'];

//Using cURL php extension to make the request to youtube API
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, YT_API_URL . $video_id);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
//$feed holds a rss feed xml returned by youtube API
$feed = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

//Using SimpleXML to parse youtube's feed
$xml = simplexml_load_string($feed);

$entry = $xml->entry[0];
//If no entry whas found, then youtube didn't find any video with specified id
if(!$entry) exit('Error: no video with id "' . $video_id . '" whas found. Please specify the id of a existing video.');
$media = $entry->children('media', true);
$group = $media->group;

$title = $group->title;//$title: The video title
$desc = $group->description;//$desc: The video description
$vid_keywords = $group->keywords;//$vid_keywords: The video keywords
$thumb = $group->thumbnail[0];//There are 4 thumbnails, the first one (index 0) is the largest.
//$thumb_url: the url of the thumbnail. $thumb_width: thumbnail width in pixels.
//$thumb_height: thumbnail height in pixels. $thumb_time: thumbnail time in the video
list($thumb_url, $thumb_width, $thumb_height, $thumb_time) = $thumb->attributes();
$content_attributes = $group->content->attributes();
//$vid_duration: the duration of the video in seconds. Ex.: 192.
$vid_duration = $content_attributes['duration'];
//$duration_formatted: the duration of the video formatted in "mm:ss". Ex.:01:54
$duration_formatted = str_pad(floor($vid_duration/60), 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) . ':' . str_pad($vid_duration%60, 2, '0', 

STR_PAD_LEFT);

//echoing the variables for testing purposes:
echo 'title: ' . $title . '<br />';
echo 'desc: ' . $desc . '<br />';
echo 'thumbnail url: ' . $thumb_url . '<br />';
?>
```